# C# WMI deleting objects before garbage collection

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm frequently polling a lot of things in WMI and occasionally get Generic WMI exceptions indicating that I've used up too many resources (memory / handles).

Would calling `ManagementObject.Delete` reduce occurrences of these errors?

Thanks

Comment: Are you `Dispose`ing stuff when you're done with it?  Or wrapping their use up in a `using` block (same thing, just automated)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ManagementObject is IDisposable so when you're done with one, call Dispose() on it.

The preferred method is in a `using(...) { ... }` block but that is secondary.